# Dozer giving me the Exception

Tags: java, spring, dozer

As I am new to Dozer, I implement it in our project .But when we are trying to storing the values into database MySQL.we are getting the following exception .But even searched in Google but they have told to configure the dozen in XML file.May i Know that is the problem I am facing

```
org.dozer.MappingException: Unable to locate dozer mapping file [dozer-bean-mappings.xml] in the classpath
```

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Make sure the mapping file is contained in the runtime classpath.

Comment: Can you post your spring config file also...

Comment: may i now what to put and where to put the mapping file..

Comment: @vinayveluri  my dozer bean in spring config   <bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
  <property name="mappingFiles">
   <list>
    <value>dozer-global-configuration.xml</value>
    <value>dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
    <value>more-dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

Answer (score 1):

If that is maven driven project place the file in the **resources** folder.

and give the path as **classpath:dozer-global-configuration.xml**

Or

Place the file some where in your local drive and give the complete path, some thing like the below.

**file:///C:/dozer-global-configuration.xml**

see [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/91723-access-external-properties-file-from-spring-context-file) and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340713/unable-to-find-spring-configuration-resource-in-applicationcontext-xml) for better understanding.

Comment: <property name="location"><value>file:///c:/test/application.properties</value></property>  in application.properties what can i find , i even don't have any file path which you have mentioned...

Comment: @ManetiVinay, the exception with the code that is given, code is not able to find the mapping file. Place your mapping file in some location of your drive and point that location to the mapping files list. <bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
 <property name="mappingFiles"> 
  <list>
   <value>file:///c:/dozer-global-configuration.xml</value> 
   <value>file:///c:/dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value> 
   <value>file:///c:/more-dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value> 
  </list> 
 </property> 
</bean>. This is the place where the file location to be changed.

Comment: file:///C:/dozer-global-configuration.xml   This worked finally thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet :

```
final List<String> mappingFilesNames = new ArrayList<String>();

String path = new File("dozerBeanMapping.xml").getAbsolutePath();

mappingFilesNames.add("file:/"+path);

mapper.setMappingFiles(mappingFilesNames);
```

here dozerBeanMapping.xml is my mapping xml file placed in project directory:
*ProjectDozer/dozerBeanMapping.xml*